# Match pattern matching based on length of list

Tags: scala, idioms

Here `recentest` is a list and I want to match on its "profile": either empty or exactly one element. Can I do it natively in a match statement?

```
val newId = if( recentest.size == 0) 0L
    else {recentest(0).as[Long]("item_id") + 1}
```

Comment: Note that `recentest.headOption.fold(0L, _.as[Long]("item_id") + 1)` or `recentest.headOption.map(_.as[Long]("item_id") + 1).getOrElse(0L)` would arguably be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val newId = recentest match {
   case Nil    => 0
   case h::Nil => h.as[Long]("item_id") + 1
}
```

Comment: Could you generalize to 2 (or more)?

Comment: @aitchnyu `... case Nil => 0; case xs => xs.map(x => x.as[Long]("...")).sum + 1` if I got it correctly. Perhaps you only need map step or similar logic.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match an arbitrary size among several cases you could do this:

```
list match {
  ...
  case _ if list.length == mySize => ...
  ...
}
```